# What is this inner product called?

Tags: linear-algebra

While trying to define an inner product, I realized that what I ended up with was a special case of the following. It seems like it should be a standard way to define an inner product, but I'm not sure what it's called.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\varphi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a linear functional. Define $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\varphi} : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as follows for $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in V$:

$$\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle_{\varphi}=\varphi(\alpha)\overline{\varphi(\beta)}$$

Comment: If $dim V\geq 2$ then it fails to be positive definite.

Comment: Somewhat related, as you may know, is that if $V$ is finite dimensional and given any inner product, then there exists $\beta\in V$ such that for all $\alpha\in V$, $\varphi(\alpha)=\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$.  (This also applies [if $V$ is a complete inner product space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#The_Hilbert_space_representation_theorem) and $\varphi$ is continuous.)

Comment: Thanks @azarel. I forgot that not only does $\langle \alpha, \alpha \rangle_{\varphi} \ge 0$, but equality only occurs when $\alpha=0$.

Comment: This "semi"-inner product is composition of $\phi$ with an inner product on the range of $\phi$, which is $1$ dimensional.  More generally if $T:V\to W$ is linear and $W$ is an inner product space, then $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle_T=\langle T(\alpha),T(\beta)\rangle$ defines a "semi"-inner product on $V$, which is definite if and only if $T$ is injective.  (I don't know of any name.  I also put "semi" in quotes because semi-inner product sometimes means something other than this.)